# combined max and min of two input number fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

```
    <!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->

        <!-- language: lang-js -->

    //this changes the values dynamically when selecting numbers

    function ClickToEditCtrl($scope) {

    var option =  document.getElementById("dropdown");





      $scope.title = "Welcome to this demo!";


      $scope.update = function (source){  

        //this part is done. Replace logic here.
       //alert(source);
       //option 1 solo person 
       if(option.value=="1"){

          var getMax = 1;

     if(source == "male"){
     $scope.res.female = getMax - $scope.res.male;
        }

           if(source == "female") {
    $scope.res.male = getMax - $scope.res.female;
       }


      }
    //option 2  ensembley
    if(option.value=="2"){

          var getMax = 15;

     if(source == "male"){
     $scope.res.female = getMax - $scope.res.male;
        }

           if(source == "female") {
    $scope.res.male = getMax - $scope.res.female;
       }


      }
    //option 3 chior
      if(option.value=="3"){

          var getMax = 25;

     if(source == "male"){
     $scope.res.female = getMax - $scope.res.male;
        }

           if(source == "female") {
    $scope.res.male = getMax - $scope.res.female;
       }


      }



    }


    } 

    <!-- language: lang-html -->

    <table >

      <!--FIRST ROW OF ENTRIES-->
      <tr>

            </select></td>
        <td class="tg-yw41"><select class="dropdown" id="dropdown" name="category1[]"  onchange="changeValue(this)" /> required> 
                <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
    <option value="1" id="1"> A-Solo 1 person</option>
    <option value="2" id="2" >B-Ensemble 2-15 persons</option>
    <option value="3" id="3">C-Choirs 16-25 persons</option>

            </select> </td>

        <td class="tg-yw4l" style="margin-left:-20px;"><input id="male"  name="numMales1[]" class="male" type="number"   style="margin: 0 0rem 1rem;"  onkeypress='validate(event)' ng-model="res.male1"  ng-change="update('male')" required/> </td>
        <td class="tg-yw4l"><input id="female"   name="numFemales1" class="female" type="number"  style="margin: 0 0rem 1rem;" onkeypress='validate(event)' ng-model="res.female1" ng-change="update('female')" required/> </td>

      </tr>

    </table>
 <!-- language: lang-html -->
  <!--SECOND ROW OF ENTRIES-->
          <table >

      <tr>

            </select></td>
        <td class="tg-yw41"><select class="dropdown" id="dropdown" name="category1[]"  onchange="changeValue(this)" /> required> 
                <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
    <option value="1" id="1"> A-Solo 1 person</option>
    <option value="2" id="2" >B-Ensemble 2-15 persons</option>
    <option value="3" id="3">C-Choirs 16-25 persons</option>

            </select> </td>

        <td class="tg-yw4l" style="margin-left:-20px;"><input id="male"  name="numMales1[]" class="male" type="number"   style="margin: 0 0rem 1rem;"  onkeypress='validate(event)' ng-model="res.male1"  ng-change="update('male')" required/> </td>
        <td class="tg-yw4l"><input id="female"   name="numFemales1" class="female" type="number"  style="margin: 0 0rem 1rem;" onkeypress='validate(event)' ng-model="res.female1" ng-change="update('female')" required/> </td>

      </tr>

    <!--SECOND ROW OF ENTRIES-->

    </table>
```

so i have duplicated the tables, as you can see if you try to apply the angularjs code to the both of them no matter if i change the ng-model name it still changes all of them at once.  what i want is to let them change independently so if i select option 1 in table 1 the from dropdown it should set the male and female to max 1 and 0 accordingly. That works fine until i select the other option from table 2 then it starts changing both table 1 and 2 and conflicting with each other. Need help with this.

Comment: Your snippet is not working. Please check. Thank you

Comment: just edited it. should be working now

Comment: you `validate()` function is undefined on snippet.

Comment: dont worry about that it belongs to another function that i use to validate

Comment: i just want someone to help me with the angularjs part or if it can be done in jquery would be thankful. i tried to edit a code on jsfilder that is close but it wont work

Comment: The question is: why jQuery and Angular together?

Comment: Ok. Actually the problem is i'm unable to understand what are you trying to achieve. What I understand is you want user to select from dropdown an option. On its selection you just want the two inputs to have their min and max set ? Am I somewhat right ?

Comment: @amkhan i have that code already working. now i want the two input fields to minus from each other as they enter a number based on the max for both fields. So for example: if the max is 2,  and i enter 2 in field one then field 2 should dynamically have 0 remaining.

Comment: Creating a JsFiddle for you

Comment: thanks you thats mighty good

Comment: Shared a link. Is this what you are saying. Please tell me further so i can improve it, if this is not what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **`ng-change`** directive for this purpose. I have created a small JsFiddle. 
Please check this [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5DMjt/7777/).

```
<div>
  <label>male</label>
  <input type="number" min="0" max="5" ng-model="res.male"  ng-change="update('male')">
</div>
<div>
  <label>female</label>
  <input type="number" min="0" max="5" ng-model="res.female" ng-change="update('female')">
</div>
```

---

```
  $scope.update = function (source){  

    var getMax = 5; //as you have said this part is done. Replace your logic here.
    //alert(source);
    if(source == "male"){
        $scope.res.female = getMax - $scope.res.male;
    }
    if(source == "female") {
        $scope.res.male = getMax - $scope.res.female;
    }
  }
```

Comment: gonna try it now hope it works with the existing jquery i have already that does the max and min dynamically

Comment: If it helps please to notify me or else I can change it according to your need.

Comment: for some reason its not working inside of table tags

Comment: you mean `model` is not updating ? Is it possible for you to share your code so that i can look into it properly ?

Comment: Sure. Make a new JsFiddle for it

Comment: If possible @ShannaChambers please upvote the answer too if it helped. Thank you :)

Comment: yes it helped but @Abdul Moiz Khan it does not work on multiple tables wit same input names.

Comment: Can you give some example from your code. So that i can understand

Comment: i just updated the code so you can check what i am trying to do

Comment: It is working but if you read what I said below it. It cant work when I duplicate the tables. It only works on a single table. So for example if I have four input fields of type number all the same it changes all of them one time I only want it to change them independently based on drop down selection. Copy the code and check it.

Comment: for the next two you have to create different `ng-model` for example `ng-model="res.male2"` and `ng-model=res.female2`. If you will use the same model it will update all the model with the same  `ng-model`

Comment: But I have an array of inputs so how is that going to work?  Plus the inputs are generated by jQuery in an array so it seems I need the jquery alternative to that code to get it work if it is possible. Please help!

Comment: am sorry to say but it still not working when i change the ng-model

Comment: can you share or show me some code ? As like this it is quite difficult to know how you are trying it

Comment: Just copy the code up top then copy and paste the first table that will make it two tables then you will see how it behaves and i tried what you said.  Its still behaving the same way it doesn't work if the input fields are in an array. Just as you can see from the table with inputs above they are in an array. so that's the problem am having.

Comment: Here. I have update it. http://jsfiddle.net/5DMjt/7793/ . Hope this is what you want. And please either use `AngularJS` or `JQuery`. Things will be easy for you.

Comment: Ok thanks Am gonna try it now and see. looking at it though I can see you forgot to duplicate the tables. I will try and adjust it and report back if its working. Thanks once again.

Comment: it seems like what i am trying to do is impossible

Comment: check out this http://jsfiddle.net/tripplex/5DMjt/7856/ and you'll see what i want.

Comment: Here Updated it please check. I hope this is what you want:
http://jsfiddle.net/5DMjt/7859/

Comment: First thing to solve a problem is you have to believe that "Nothing is impossible". Else it would be impossible :)

Comment: check this out  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38754713/call-angulajs-function-in-jquery-append