# Call AngularJS function in jQuery append

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

How would one call that AngularJS function in this dynamic jQuery input fields?

As you can see I tried calling it the regular way in the html tags but it doesn't work.

I would really appreciate if someone could show me how this would be done. Thanks.

```js
function ClickToEditCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.changeValue = function(ctrl, cmbSource) {

    var option = 0;
    if (cmbSource == 1) {
      option = $scope.mySelect0;
    } else if (cmbSource == 2) {
      option = $scope.mySelect1;
    }

    if (option == '1') {
      if (cmbSource == 1) {
        $scope.max1 = 1;
        $scope.min = 0;

      }
      if (cmbSource == 2) {
        $scope.max2 = 1;
        $scope.min = 0;
      }

    } else if (option == '2') {
      if (cmbSource == 1) {
        $scope.max1 = 15;
        $scope.min = 0;
      }
      if (cmbSource == 2) {
        $scope.max2 = 15;
        $scope.min = 0;
      }


    } else if (option == '3') {
      if (cmbSource == 1) {
        $scope.max1 = 25;
        $scope.min = 0;
      }
      if (cmbSource == 2) {
        $scope.max2 = 25;
        $scope.min = 0;
      }



    }
    //alert($scope.mySelect);
  }
  $scope.validate = function($event) {
    //ng-keypress="validate($event)"
    //console.log($event);
  }
  $scope.update = function(source, $event, cmbSource) {
    $scope.validate($event);
    var option = 0;
    if (cmbSource == 1) {
      option = $scope.mySelect0;
    } else if (cmbSource == 2) {
      option = $scope.mySelect1;
    }

    //option 1 solo person 
    if (option == 1) {

      var getMax = 1;
      if (source == "male") {
        if (cmbSource == 1) {
          $scope.set0.female = getMax - $scope.set0.male;
        } else if (cmbSource == 2) {
          $scope.set1.female = getMax - $scope.set1.male;
        }
      }
      if (source == "female") {
        if (cmbSource == 1) {
          $scope.set0.male = getMax - $scope.set0.female;
        } else if (cmbSource == 2) {
          $scope.set1.male = getMax - $scope.set1.female;
        }
      }
    }
    //option 2  ensembley
    if (option == "2") {

      var getMax = 15;

      if (source == "male") {
        if (cmbSource == 1) {
          $scope.set0.female = getMax - $scope.set0.male;
        } else if (cmbSource == 2) {
          $scope.set1.female = getMax - $scope.set1.male;
        }
      }

      if (source == "female") {
        if (cmbSource == 1) {
          $scope.set0.male = getMax - $scope.set0.female;
        } else if (cmbSource == 2) {
          $scope.set1.male = getMax - $scope.set1.female;
        }
      }
    }
    //option 3 chior
    if (option == "3") {

      var getMax = 25;

      if (source == "male") {
        if (cmbSource == 1) {
          $scope.set0.female = getMax - $scope.set0.male;
        } else if (cmbSource == 2) {
          $scope.set1.female = getMax - $scope.set1.male;
        }
      }

      if (source == "female") {
        if (cmbSource == 1) {
          $scope.set0.male = getMax - $scope.set0.female;
        } else if (cmbSource == 2) {
          $scope.set1.male = getMax - $scope.set1.female;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


$(document).ready(function() {

  var
  var max_fields = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
  var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
  var add_button = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

  var x = 1; //initlal text box count
  $(add_button).click(function(e) { //on add input button click
    e.preventDefault();
    if (x < max_fields) { //max input box allowed
      x++; //text box increment
      $(wrapper).append('<div><table class="tg" style="color:black; font-size: 80%;" cellspacing="0"><tr><td class="tg-yw4l" width="45px"><select class="" id="element_10" name="class1[]"  style="margin: 0 1rem 1rem 0rem; padding-right:-10px;"><option value="" selected="selected"></option><option value="1" >class 1</option><option value="2" >class 2</option><option value="3" >class 3</option><option value="4" >class 4</option><option value="5" >class 5</option><option value="6" >class 6</option><option value="7" >class 7</option></select></td><td class="tg-yw4l" width="45px;"><select class="" id="dropdown" name="category1[]" ng-change="changeValue(this,2)" ng-model="mySelect1"><option value="" selected="selected"></option><option value="1" >A-Solo 1 person</option><option value="2" >B-Ensemble 2-15 persons</option><option value="3" >C-Choirs 16-25 persons</option></select></td><td class="tg-yw4l" width="181px"><input id="element_2" name="entrytitle1[]" class="" type="text" maxlength="255" value="" style="margin: 0rem 0rem 1rem;" /></td><td class="tg-yw4l" width="185px"><textarea id="element_2" name="entryname1[]" class="element textarea small" onclick="myFunctionAlert()" required style=" height: 0px; font-size:150%; color:black; line-height:1.4rem;"></textarea></td><td class="tg-yw4l" style="margin-left:-20px;" width="40px;"><input id="male" name="numMales1[]" class="male" type="number"  onkeypress="validate(event)" min="0" max="{{max2}}" ng-model="set1.male" ng-change="update(&#39;male&#39;,this,2)" /></td><td class="tg-yw4l" width="48px;"><input id="female" name="numFemales1[]" class="female" type="number" onkeypress="validate(event)" ng-model="set1.female" min="0" max="{{max2}}" ng-change="update(&#39;female&#39;,this,2)"/></td><td class="tg-yw4l" width="125px"><input id="element_2" name="composer1[]" class="" type="text" maxlength="255" value="" style="margin: 0 0rem 1rem;"/></td></tr></table><a href="#" class="remove_field warning hollow button tiny" style="float:right;">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box

    }
  });

  $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function(e) { //user click on remove text
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
    x--;
  })
});


< !html-- >
```

Comment: You shouldn't. If you are using Angular you should be creating you dynamic elements with Angular templates. If you are just learning Angular, leave jQuery out of the project for a bit while you get used to the way it works and if you need some jQuery magic, learn about how directives work.

Comment: Why the down vote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be enough to get you going.

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('ClickToEditCtrl', function() {
  var vm = this;
  
  vm.sets = [{}];
  
  vm.addSet = function() {
    vm.sets.push({
      
    });
  };
  
  vm.remove = function(set) {
    vm.sets.splice(vm.sets.indexOf(set), 1);
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="ClickToEditCtrl as vm">
      <div class="input_fields_wrap"> 
<table>
    <!--FIRST ROW OF ENTRIES-->
    <tr ng-repeat="set in vm.sets">
        <td class="tg-yw41">
            <select class="dropdown" id="dropdown" name="category" ng-model="group.category" required>
                <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
                <option value="1" id="1"> A-Solo 1 person</option>
                <option value="2" id="2">B-Ensemble 2-15 persons</option>
                <option value="3" id="3">C-Choirs 16-25 persons</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td class="tg-yw4l" style="margin-left:-20px;"><input id="male" name="numMales1[" class="male" type="number" style="margin: 0 0rem 1rem;" min="0" max="{{max1}}" ng-model="set.male" ng-required /> </td>
        <td class="tg-yw4l"><input id="female" name="numFemales1" class="female" type="number" style="margin: 0 0rem 1rem;" ng-model="set.female" min="0" max="{{max1}}" ng-required /> </td>

        <td><button ng-click="vm.remove(set)">Remove</button></td>
    </tr>
    <!--SECOND ROW OF ENTRIES-->
</table>


  </div>
  <button class="add_field_button secondary hollow button" name="addmore"><span style="color:white;" ng-click="vm.addSet()">Add More Fields</span></button><br/>


  <p>max1 = {{max1}} </p>
  <p>min = {{min}} </p>
  <p>max2 = {{max2}} </p>
  <p>min = {{min}} </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ok tried that but you changed some elements in the input fields and select option. so the code is working still but i would want all functions in angular file i have working together.

Comment: ok the code i have was working on the first static field but when wrote the jquery code to generate the fields dynamic and placed the function call in the jquery it didn't call the function so there lies the problem.

Comment: could i just email all the code i have i placed all of it on jsfiddler but you dont seem to understand what i am trying to accomplish

Comment: I understand what you are trying to do, it is not hard at all. I am not going to write the app for you, I was trying to help you out and get you started in the Angular way.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it the Angular way.

```js
angular.module('testApp', []).controller('testController', function() {
  var vm = this;
  
  vm.items = [];
  
  var numberAdded = 1;
  
  vm.add = function() {
    vm.items.push(numberAdded++);
  }
  
  vm.remove = function(item) {
    vm.items.splice(vm.items.indexOf(item), 1);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<span ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testController as vm">
  <button ng-click="vm.add()">Add</button>
  <div ng-repeat="item in vm.items">
    Dynamically Added {{item}}
    <button ng-click="vm.remove(item)">Remove</button>
  </div>
</span>
```

Comment: ok so if i do it angular way can i call the function that generates the fields plus the functions that i have already in angularjs all together in one input fields.

Comment: can you use jsfiddler copy my code and create a html with it. see how it would work

Comment: Have a look at the ng-repeat block I have. Take the html you have in your append call and put an ng-repeat on that. Also look into Angular form validation. You have a lot to learn, I was just making a simple example to get your head into the Angular space. I moved the remove button into the generated block to show you how that is possible.

Comment: i dont know if i am not understanding you or if its you who is not understanding me. what i am doing is very complex.